# Why is it that in Bootstrap in phone-view the collapse of my navigation goes over my logo in my nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Ok so here is my code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="navbar" style="margin-bottom:1px;">

  <div class="navbar-inner">

      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="#"/></a> <!--logo here in brand----------->
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">

    <ul class="nav pull-right">
 <li><a href="#"><span style="color:#00bfff;">HOME</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#">SCHEDULE</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LEARN</a></li>
<li><a href="#">COVER MAP</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!--nav-collapse-->
    </div><!--container END-->
</div><!--navbar-inner END-->
</div><!--navbar END-->
</div><!--row END-->
```

When I decrease the size of my screen to mobile view which is the phone view, the collapse I created for my navigation to go in the little white box when in tablet view is fine, but when I get to the phone view, which is smaller, that little navigation box goes OVER my logo which is an img in the brand section and pushes that logo down.. sort of like a padding but i dont know really it just goes on top of my logo and pushes the logo down. I want it to remain on the side of the logo with out pushing it down even if my logo gets smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Give to the container of the logo width: 100% and float:left; in mobile media query it will work

Comment: im not to sure exactly what you mean but I tryed giving the .brand and the .navbar-inner a width of 100% and float left and that did not work. if im not doing it correct can you give me an example

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of it?

Comment: I do not see the example.... I have not provided the CSS but just picture a black nav bar going across the screen with nav hyper links on it and a logo picture on the left where the (brand is).. now if you were to minimize the window to mobile size that little collapse that closes all the navs together would go over my logo instead of remaining on the right side. I need to to remain on the side of the logo